# Getting access to a DOM element after closing Angular-Bootstrap $modal instance

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Malhar Dashboard widget framework at the moment, and struggling with an issue in the `close` event of the Bootstrap Modal.

FYI: https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard

Specifically, when I close the modal and arrive back to the `$modalInstance.result.then` function, I need to have access to the parent container which launched the modal in the first place. This proves to be difficult.

For example, when certain click events are triggered, I can get access to the Kendo UI chart element as follows :

```
    var chart = widget.find('.k-chart').data("kendoChart");
    chart.resize($(".k-chart"));
```

But after having launched the $modal like this :

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
```

I want to close the $modal, and still get access to that Kendo chart widget in the `modalInstance.result.then()` section - but `widget` is `undefined`:

```
 modalInstance.result.then(
        function (result) {
             var chart = widget.find('.k-chart').data("kendoChart"); // widget UNDEFINED !!!
        }
    )
```

**** UPDATE - Two things: ****

1) On a positive note, I can get access to the parent node of `.modal-body`; however, I don't think my solution is very elegenant with the use of `el.parent().parent().parent().parent().find()` .

2) On the downside, although I can call the `kendo.resize()` function, it has no effect.

Help is appreciated.

```js
// Set resolve and reject callbacks for the result promise
modalInstance.result.then(
function (result) {

 // Call the close callback
 onClose(result, widget, scope);
 
 if (!widget.gadgetConfigured) {
  widget.gadgetConfigured = true;  
  widget.setHeight(widget.fixedSize.height);
  widget.setWidth(widget.fixedSize.width);                            
 }                        

 scope.$broadcast('widgetSettingsClosed', widget, result);
 
 // attempt to refresh kendo chart - 04/30/2015 BM:             
 var el = $('.modal-body');
 var chartElem = el.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.k-chart').data("kendoChart");
 if (chartElem != undefined) {
  chartElem.setOptions({ chartArea: { width: chartElem.getSize().width * .95, height: chartElem.getSize().height * .90 } });                            
  chartElem.resize($(".k-chart"));
 }                          
 scope.$emit('widgetChanged', widget);
},
function (reason) {
 // Call the dismiss callback
 onDismiss(reason, scope);
}
);
```

Comment: have you read the docs for angular-ui modal? Should help you  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: yes, and trying to glean some ideas from the docs, thank you

Comment: added jquery selector to get access to DOM elemnet on `var el = $('.modal-body');` . However, the `chartElem.resize()` line still has NO affect. The same code works when triggered by click events.